# How to manually sort a map in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map of custom classes, and there are certain cases where I edit the value of a key in the map, without taking it out of the map. After making these changes, I want to re-sort the map, so that the order in which the keys are looped over corrects for this change in the key value. However, I would like to do this without removing the element and re-inserting it back in (since I noticed that insert reorders every time), since this is being done in a loop, and it would mess up the iteration order. Is there a way to just simply reorder the entire map after my loop is done? I would be using the map's default comparer to reorder.

edit* This is std::map

Comment: Are you talking about `std::map`? If so, then you can't do this. If not, please provide more details.

Comment: @juanchopanza  Yes, this is std::map. Sorry forgot to include it. Would the workaround be adding a dummy element and removing it?

Comment: So, you cant do that. You can't modify the keys and you can't change the relative ordering of elements for a given type of map.

Comment: @juanchopanza I see. That's a shame, but it makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: You could instantiate a different map that uses a different sorting criteria, and instantiate it using the elements of the original map.

Comment: How about removing those elements and putting them into a new map (under new keys), then after the loop is done, inserting the new map back into the old one?

Comment: Many workarounds possible, e.g. moving the elements you want to "re-key" out of the `map` and into e.g. a `list` or `vector`, then after you complete the `map` iterator re-inserting those values with the new keys. Or, you could have a container of pair<string,string> with from,to keys for renaming after iteration.  Alternatively, you could put some kind of "already processed" flag into the elements, setting it when erasing/inserting elements with new keys that are later in the iteration order, and do a clear-flag and skip when encountering it during iteration.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Essentially you are asking about two thing you cannot do with a map: Change the keys of the elements (you should get a compiler error for trying) and keeping the map in an unordered state, which violates one of its basic invariants (the elements in a map are always sorted). So the answer is most likely: "don't use a map or use a different algorithm", but in order to suggest a better data structure / algorithm, we need to know, why you chose `std::map` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I would be rethinking your approach in general if you're wanting to modify keys in a map without having to delete or insert elements in the map. You're trying to do something that the std::map (or any associative container) is not built to do. I'm assuming you're worried about performance. Insertion and deletion in a map are O(log n) operations just like a find(). Doing this type of work in a loop would not be a big problem performance wise, but if you're working on a piece of critical code that must run as fast as possible, then I can see where you might be more concerned about speed here.